# Trying to connect to a S3 Bucket with Hadoop FileSystem but jumps an error saying the bucket is in this region

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, hadoop, amazon-s3

I'm trying to use the Hadoop API to connect to an Amazon S3 bucket. I'm using the org.apache.hadoop.fs.FileSystem class in order to connect to the bucket and create a new file.

```
import org.apache.hadoop.conf.Configuration;
import org.apache.hadoop.fs.*;
import java.net.URI;
public class FileMover {

public static void main(String [] args) {

    URI s3uri=URI.create(“s3a://mybucket”);
    Configuration conf = new Configuration();
    FileSystem s3fs=FileSystem.get(s3uri,conf);
    s3fs.create(new Path(“s3a://mybucket/MyFile”));
 }

}
```

But this generates the following error

```
org.apache.hadoop.fs.s3a.AWSS3IOException: getFileStatus on s3a://mybucket/Jesus/test: com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.AmazonS3Exception: 
The bucket is in this region: eu-west-3. 
Please use this region to retry the request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 301; Error Code: 301 Moved Permanently; Request ID: 3D3A4C0CE06CCF8B), S3 Extended Request ID: rDKHmonuOeVi2PhwTZ3ByLD3LGBZ+kbTvqwZ8/hfUAs8y9ei88HosVSuOqdGJa8VtjvOXZ8/DiE=: 
The bucket is in this region: eu-west-3. Please use this region to retry the request (Service: Amazon S3; Status Code: 301; Error Code: 301 Moved Permanently; Request ID: 3D3A4C0CE06CCF8B)
```

This is the configuration i set in the core-site.xml

```
<configuration>
  <property>
    <name>fs.defaultFS</name>
    <value>hdfs://quickstart.cloudera:8020</value>
  </property>



  <property>
    <name>fs.s3a.access.key</name>
    <value>XXXXXXXXXXXX</value>
  </property>

  <property>
    <name>fs.s3a.secret.key</name>
    <value>XXXXXXXXXXXX</value>
  </property>


  <!-- OOZIE proxy user setting -->
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.oozie.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>

  <!-- HTTPFS proxy user setting -->
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.httpfs.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.httpfs.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>

  <!-- Llama proxy user setting -->
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.llama.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.llama.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>

  <!-- Hue proxy user setting -->
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hue.hosts</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>
  <property>
    <name>hadoop.proxyuser.hue.groups</name>
    <value>*</value>
  </property>

</configuration>
```

I tried to set the endpoint in the core-site.xml to the one requested in the error but it doesn't work.

Comment: Why can't you just use AWS Java SDK?

Comment: Because i have to transfer data between a hadoop cluster and a s3 bucket

Comment: Have you tried setting `fs.s3a.endpoint` to not use the default us east region? https://hadoop.apache.org/docs/stable/hadoop-aws/tools/hadoop-aws/index.html#Using_Per-Bucket_Configuration_to_access_data_round_the_world